# how to optimize my code in terms of runtime

Tags: c, matrix

```
#include "fmm.h"
// Slow fmm :)

void basefmm(int n, int* m1, int* m2, int* result, int* col1) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            col1[k] = m2[k * n + j];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int x = i * n;
            result[i * n + j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k ++) {
                result[x + j] += m1[x + k] * col1[k];
            }  
        }
    }
}
            
int* add(int n, int* m1, int* m2) {
    int* res = malloc(n * n * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            res[i * n + j] = m1[i * n + j] + m2[i * n + j];
        }
    }

    return res;
}

int* sub(int n, int* m1, int* m2) {
    int* res = malloc(n * n * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            res[i * n + j] = m1[i * n + j] - m2[i * n + j];
        }
    }
    return res;
}

void fmm(int n, int* m1, int* m2, int* result) {
    int* col1 = malloc(64 * sizeof(int));

    if (n < 64) {
        basefmm(n, m1, m2, result, col1);
        return;
    }

    n = n / 2;
    int nsquare = n * n;
    int size = nsquare * sizeof(int);
    int* A = malloc(size);
    int* B = malloc(size);
    int* C = malloc(size);
    int* D = malloc(size);
    int* E = malloc(size);
    int* F = malloc(size);
    int* G = malloc(size);
    int* H = malloc(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0;j < n; j++) {
            int x = i * n;
            A[x + j] = m1[i * n * 2 + j];
            E[x + j] = m2[i * n * 2 + j];
            C[x + j] = m1[(i + n) * 2 * n + j];
            G[x + j] = m2[(i + n) * 2 * n + j];
            B[x + j] = m1[i * n * 2 + j + n];
            F[x + j] = m2[i * n * 2 + j + n];
            D[x + j] = m1[(i + n) * n * 2 + j + n];
            H[x + j] = m2[(i + n) * n * 2 + j + n];
        }
    }

    int* p1 = malloc(size);
    int* p2 = malloc(size);
    int* p3 = malloc(size);
    int* p4 = malloc(size);
    int* p5 = malloc(size);
    int* p6 = malloc(size);
    int* p7 = malloc(size);
    fmm(n, add(n, A, D), add(n, E, H), p1);
    fmm(n, D, sub(n, G, E), p2);
    fmm(n, add(n, A, B), H, p3);
    fmm(n, sub(n,B,D),add(n,G,H),p4);
    fmm(n, A, sub(n, F, H), p5);
    fmm(n, add(n, C, D), E, p6);
    fmm(n, sub(n, A, C), add(n, E, F), p7);
    int* C11 = A;
    int* C12 = B;
    int* C21 = C;
    int* C22 = D;
    C11 = add(n, p1, p2);
    C11 = sub(n, C11, p3);
    C11 = add(n, C11, p4);
    C12 = add(n, p5, p3);
    C21 = add(n, p6, p2);
    C22 = add(n, p5, p1);
    C22 = sub(n, C22, p6);
    C22 = sub(n, C22, p7);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            int x = i * n;
            result[x * 2 + j] = C11[x + j];
            result[(i + n) * n * 2 + j] = C21[x + j];
            result[x * 2 + j + n] = C12[x + j];
            result[(i + n) * n * 2 + j + n] = C22[x + j];
        }
    }
}
```

this is my code,in my homework i was asked to multiply 2 matrixes(n is a power of 2) as fast as possible right now the code is running at 400ms on my computer is there any way to make it run faster(in this code aij=a[i*n+J]

i am using strassen algorithem and tried to optimized the base and i dont know what else to do to make this code run faster so if you could give some tips it would help a lot

Comment: You seem to have a lot of malloc calls with no freeing of memory.

Comment: But how freeing would make the program run faster?

Comment: It wouldn't but it's not a good habit to develop. If this is homework. the teacher shouldn't ignore bad memory practices.

Comment: Avoid as many multiplications as you can, by precomputing values, saving them to variables, and reusing the variables.

Comment: Do one big malloc in the beginning, not many small ones. Don't do malloc in a recursive function, do it before you call the recursive function.

Comment: Potentially relevant: [Optimized matrix multiplication in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907557/optimized-matrix-multiplication-in-c) Found by Googling "fast matrix multiplication c" and choosing the first result.

Comment: First, [use a profiler](https://marketsplash.com/tutorials/c/c-programming-code-profiling/) to find out where your program is spending all its time.

Comment: @ItayDerazon Tip: With large `n`, `n * n * sizeof(int)` may overflow `int` math, where `sizeof(int) * n * n` may  not as it is `size_t` math.  IAC, `res = malloc(n * n * sizeof(int));` better as `res = malloc(sizeof res[0] * n * n);` to avoid type mistakes.

Comment: Before trying to do some Big-O optimizations for matrix products, make sure that your base case is optimized (using SIMD, good cache locality, etc) -- search for existing GEMM implementations (also note that `float` matrix products can be ~4 times faster than `int`, if your CPU has FMA support (but you will lose ~8 bit precision). Even `double` can be twice as fast as `int`).

Answer (score 0):

- Review: [Is premature optimization really the root of all evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80084/94903)
- Improve [O()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) where possible.
- This code deserve better memory management.  Minor improvement: Reduce `malloc()` calls.

```
    // int* A = malloc(size);
    // ... 
    // int* H = malloc(size);

    size_t size = nsquare * sizeof(int);
    int* A = malloc(size * 8);
    int* B = A + nsquare;
    int* C = B + nsquare;
    ...     
    int* H = G + nsquare;
    // Be sure to only `free(A)`
```

- Profile other potential ideas:

Comment: Improving asymptotic time complexity compared to a correctly implemented Strassen definitely won’t help make matrix multiplication faster unless the OP discovers a revolutionary new algorithm.

Comment: @Ry- The larger concern is that OP appears to be overly concerned about minor performance issues. Improvements like better memory handling can bring linear improvements, yet it is better to first see if algorithm improvements are reasonably possible.  That investigation may fail as you suggest, yet it deserves prior consideration.